# Why is my linker trying to link against old iOS SDK?

Tags: ios, xcode, linker

I'm able to build my iOS project right now, but I'm getting two warnings like the following that are really annoying me:

```
ld: warning: directory not found for option
    '-L/Users/brennon/Development/MobileMuse/BioAudio/../../Developer/Platforms/iPhoneOS.platform/Developer/SDKs/iPhoneOS4.2.sdk/lib'
```

(I've broken the compiler command over several lines in a futile attempt at readability):

```
Ld /Users/brennon/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/BioAudio-avxobobusfxeffaswkzteodevihm/Build/Intermediates/BioAudio.build/Debug-iphoneos/BioAudio.build/Objects-normal/armv7/BioAudio normal armv7
    cd /Users/brennon/Development/MobileMuse/BioAudio
    setenv IPHONEOS_DEPLOYMENT_TARGET 4.3
    setenv PATH "/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneOS.platform/Developer/usr/bin:/Developer/usr/bin:/usr/bin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/sbin"
    /Developer/Platforms/iPhoneOS.platform/Developer/usr/bin/llvm-gcc-4.2 
        -arch armv7 
        -isysroot /Developer/Platforms/iPhoneOS.platform/Developer/SDKs/iPhoneOS4.3.sdk 
        -L/Users/brennon/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/BioAudio-avxobobusfxeffaswkzteodevihm/Build/Products/Debug-iphoneos 
        -L/Users/brennon/Development/MobileMuse/BioAudio 
        -L/Users/brennon/Development/MobileMuse/BioAudio/../../Developer/Platforms/iPhoneOS.platform/Developer/SDKs/iPhoneOS4.2.sdk/lib 
        -F/Users/brennon/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/BioAudio-avxobobusfxeffaswkzteodevihm/Build/Products/Debug-iphoneos 
        -filelist /Users/brennon/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/BioAudio-avxobobusfxeffaswkzteodevihm/Build/Intermediates/BioAudio.build/Debug-iphoneos/BioAudio.build/Objects-normal/armv7/BioAudio.LinkFileList 
        -dead_strip -miphoneos-version-min=4.3 -framework Foundation 
        -framework UIKit -framework CoreGraphics -framework AudioToolbox 
        -framework Security 
        -o /Users/brennon/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/BioAudio-avxobobusfxeffaswkzteodevihm/Build/Intermediates/BioAudio.build/Debug-iphoneos/BioAudio.build/Objects-normal/armv7/BioAudio
```

It seems to still be trying to link against the 4.2 SDK, which is no more since upgrading my development machine to 10.7 and, hence, Xcode.  I've scoured the Project and Target settings, and can't seem to find anything still pointing to 4.2.  Any ideas?

**EDIT:** I tried dtuckernet's answer.  Running `grep -iRF iPhoneOS4.2.sdk .` in the project directory produced the following (sorry about the mess!) output:

```
./BioAudio.xcodeproj/project.pbxproj:                   "\"$(SRCROOT)/../../Developer/Platforms/iPhoneOS.platform/Developer/SDKs/iPhoneOS4.2.sdk/lib\"",
./BioAudio.xcodeproj/project.pbxproj:                   "\"$(SRCROOT)/../../Developer/Platforms/iPhoneOS.platform/Developer/SDKs/iPhoneOS4.2.sdk/lib\"",
./BioAudio.xcodeproj/project.xcworkspace/xcuserdata/brennon.xcuserdatad/UserInterfaceState.xcuserstate:         <string>file://localhost/Users/brennon/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneOS.platform/Developer/SDKs/iPhoneOS4.2.sdk/lib/liblo.a</string>
./BioAudio.xcodeproj/project.xcworkspace/xcuserdata/brennon.xcuserdatad/UserInterfaceState.xcuserstate:     <string>file://localhost/Users/brennon/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneOS.platform/Developer/SDKs/iPhoneOS4.2.sdk/lib/liblo.a</string>
./BioAudio.xcodeproj/project.xcworkspace/xcuserdata/brennon.xcuserdatad/UserInterfaceState.xcuserstate:     <string>Directory not found for option '-L/Users/brennon/Development/MobileMuse/BioAudio/../../Developer/Platforms/iPhoneOS.platform/Developer/SDKs/iPhoneOS4.2.sdk/lib'</string>
./build/BioAudio.build/Debug-iphoneos/BioAudio.build/build-state.dat:N/Users/brennon/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneOS.platform/Developer/SDKs/iPhoneOS4.2.sdk/lib/liblo.a
./build/BioAudio.build/Debug-iphoneos/BioAudio.build/build-state.dat:N/Users/brennon/Development/BioAudio/../../Developer/Platforms/iPhoneOS.platform/Developer/SDKs/iPhoneOS4.2.sdk/lib/liblo.a
./build/BioAudio.build/Debug-iphoneos/BioAudio.build/build-state.dat:lSLF07#2@121"Link /Users/brennon/Development/BioAudio/build/BioAudio.build/Debug-iphoneos/BioAudio.build/Objects-normal/armv6/BioAudio3    /Developer/Platforms/iPhoneOS.platform/Developer/usr/bin/gcc-4.2 -arch armv6 -isysroot /Developer/Platforms/iPhoneOS.platform/Developer/SDKs/iPhoneOS4.2.sdk -L/Users/brennon/Development/BioAudio/build/Debug-iphoneos -L/Users/brennon/Development/BioAudio -L/Users/brennon/Development/BioAudio/../../Developer/Platforms/iPhoneOS.platform/Developer/SDKs/iPhoneOS4.2.sdk/lib -F/Users/brennon/Development/BioAudio/build/Debug-iphoneos -filelist /Users/brennon/Development/BioAudio/build/BioAudio.build/Debug-iphoneos/BioAudio.build/Objects-normal/armv6/BioAudio.LinkFileList -dead_strip -miphoneos-version-min=4.2 -framework Foundation -framework UIKit -framework CoreGraphics -framework AudioToolbox -llo -framework Security -o /Users/brennon/Development/BioAudio/build/BioAudio.build/Debug-iphoneos/BioAudio.build/O0#ects-normal/armv6/BioAudio
./build/BioAudio.build/Debug-iphoneos/BioAudio.build/build-state.dat:lSLF07#2@121"Link /Users/brennon/Development/BioAudio/build/BioAudio.build/Debug-iphoneos/BioAudio.build/Objects-normal/armv7/BioAudio3    /Developer/Platforms/iPhoneOS.platform/Developer/usr/bin/gcc-4.2 -arch armv7 -isysroot /Developer/Platforms/iPhoneOS.platform/Developer/SDKs/iPhoneOS4.2.sdk -L/Users/brennon/Development/BioAudio/build/Debug-iphoneos -L/Users/brennon/Development/BioAudio -L/Users/brennon/Development/BioAudio/../../Developer/Platforms/iPhoneOS.platform/Developer/SDKs/iPhoneOS4.2.sdk/lib -F/Users/brennon/Development/BioAudio/build/Debug-iphoneos -filelist /Users/brennon/Development/BioAudio/build/BioAudio.build/Debug-iphoneos/BioAudio.build/Objects-normal/armv7/BioAudio.LinkFileList -dead_strip -miphoneos-version-min=4.2 -framework Foundation -framework UIKit -framework CoreGraphics -framework AudioToolbox -llo -framework Security -o /Users/brennon/Development/BioAudio/build/BioAudio.build/Debug-iphoneos/BioAudio.build/O0#ects-normal/armv7/BioAudio
Binary file ./build/BioAudio.build/Debug-iphoneos/BioAudio.build/Objects-normal/armv6/BioAudio matches
Binary file ./build/BioAudio.build/Debug-iphoneos/BioAudio.build/Objects-normal/armv7/BioAudio matches
./build/BioAudio.build/Debug-iphonesimulator/BioAudio.build/build-state.dat:N/Users/brennon/Development/BioAudio/../../Developer/Platforms/iPhoneOS.platform/Developer/SDKs/iPhoneOS4.2.sdk/lib/liblo.a
./build/BioAudio.build/Debug-iphonesimulator/BioAudio.build/build-state.dat:old: warning: in /Users/brennon/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneOS.platform/Developer/SDKs/iPhoneOS4.2.sdk/lib/liblo.a, file was built for unsupported file format which is not the architecture being linked (i386)
./build/BioAudio.build/Debug-iphonesimulator/BioAudio.build/build-state.dat:lSLF07#2@90"Link /Users/brennon/Development/BioAudio/build/Debug-iphonesimulator/BioAudio.app/BioAudio318119306#318119307#0(372"ld: warning: in /Users/brennon/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneOS.platform/Developer/SDKs/iPhoneOS4.2.sdk/lib/liblo.a, file was built for unsupported file format which is not the architecture being linked (i3865(22@192"In /Users/brennon/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneOS.platform/Developer/SDKs/iPhoneOS4.2.sdk/lib/liblo.a, file was built for unsupported file format which is not the architecture being linked (i386)318119307#0#206#0(6@0"318119307#0#0#0#0#0"0(4@46""_lo_address_new_with_proto", referenced from:318119307#225#49#0(6@0"318119307#0#0#0#0#0"0(13@31"-[BioAudio setup] in BioAudio.o318119307#274#38#0(6@0"318119307#0#0#0#0#0"0(13@19"Symbol(s) not found318119307#312#24#0(6@0"318119307#0#0#0#0#0"0(13@35"Collect2: ld returned 1 exit status318119307#336#36#0(6@0"318119307#0#0#0#0#0"0(0#0#0"8640817536#1094"    cd /Use    /Developer/Platforms/iPhoneSimulator.platform/Developer/usr/bin/gcc-4.2 -arch i386 -isysroot /Developer/Platforms/iPhoneSimulator.platform/Developer/SDKs/iPhoneSimulator4.2.sdk -L/Users/brennon/Development/BioAudio/build/Debug-iphonesimulator -L/Users/brennon/Development/BioAudio -L/Users/brennon/Development/BioAudio/../../Developer/Platforms/iPhoneOS.platform/Developer/SDKs/iPhoneOS4.2.sdk/lib -F/Users/brennon/Development/BioAudio/build/Debug-iphonesimulator -filelist /Users/brennon/Development/BioAudio/build/BioAudio.build/Debug-iphonesimulator/BioAudio.build/Objects-normal/i386/BioAudio.LinkFileList -mmacosx-version-min=10.6 -Xlinker -objc_abi_version -Xlinker 2 -framework Foundation -framework UIKit -framework CoreGraphics -framework AudioToolbox -llo -framework Security -o /Users/brennon/Developm1#t/BioAudio/build/Debug-iphonesimulator/BioAudio.app/BioAudio
Binary file ./build/Debug-iphoneos/BioAudio.app/BioAudio matches
```

Changing the entries in `pbproject.pbxproj` to `4.3` was easy enough, but the same warnings are still thrown on build.  Cleaning still doesn't resolve anything.  I feel uneasy about just altering the plist keys in the plists under `brennon.xcuerdatad`.  I'm sure the issue is either here or in the `build-state` files, but shouldn't those be refreshed/rebuilt on a clean and build?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is still a reference somewhere in your project settings to 4.2  In the past I've used grep to go through all the files in my project and find the reference. See this example:

```
cd ~/Documents/MyProjectDirectory/
grep -iRF 4.2 .
```

This should give you all files that contain 4.2, and it should be easy to see where the 4.2 SDK is referenced.

Comment: I posted my results for this a while back--they're up in my answer.  Thanks again.

Answer (score 0):

Different configurations Debug / Release may have different settings for a target iOS. Check that configuration that you are compiling match your expectations for iOS that should be set in it.

Comment: I may still be learning (aren't we all?), but I'm not _that_ green. ;)

Comment: Just to clarify...that isn't my problem.